# Pure CSS website translate

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, lang

I have found solution for pure css translation on stackoverflow. [Here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034588/static-html-website-bootstrap-multi-language-support)

In css I have:

```
.en, .sl { display:none; } /* hide all elements with a language class */
.en:lang(en), .sl:lang(sl) { display:block; } /* show those elements that match their language class */
```

In HTML:

```
<html lang="sl">
```

and

```
<div class="sl">Pozdravljeni</div>
<div class="en">Hello</div>
```

For change of lang attribute I use js:

```
function setLang(lang) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].setAttribute('lang',lang);                 
}
```

It works ok on my computer in Chrome. It work on my iphone. On ipad mini. 
But it does NOT work on my girlfriends computer in Chrome. And not in IE.

And it seems it does NOT work on my computer on IE.

Problem is in css.
This code:

```
.en, .sl { display:none; }
```

works, and this not:

```
.en:lang(en), .sl:lang(sl) { display:block; }
```

I can't figure it out what is wrong.

Comment: The `:lang` pseudo-class doesn't work in IE until version 8, and it may require `<!DOCTYPE html>`.  It's been supported by Chrome since version 1, so if it works on your computer, it *should* work on hers.  You could try setting the language on 'body' instead of 'html'.

Comment: So you are adding all the content in all the languages you support?

Comment: That's what is weird. That it doesnt work same on both of chromes.

Comment: Your code works for me in IE11, Chrome, Safari, and Firefox:  http://jsfiddle.net/sLo1c7vy/

Answer (score 1):

You're targeting a `<div>` with the class "de" in `.de:lang(sl)`, but you don't  have any `<div>`s with the class "de".

Therefore, if you change `.de:lang(sl)` to `.sl:lang(sl)`, it should work.

Comment: that's a typo. Actually i have:  .sl:lang(sl).

Answer (score 0):

The ".en" and ".de" refer to the class names, and the ":lang(en)" and ":lang(sl)" refer to the lang attributes.

```
.en:lang(en), .de:lang(sl) { display:block; }
```

means "enable block display for any items with class 'en' and lang='en', and any items with class 'de' and lang='sl'"

Comment: The lang pseudo-class *should* be inheritable by children(?)

Comment: OK, well, now that your typo is fixed, it looks like it should work, and my comment about lang being not inherited is incorrect -- I misread the spec, it is inherited until the parser hits something that has a different lang.

Answer (score 0):

```
html[lang="en"] .de,
html[lang="en"] .sl {
    display: none;
}

html[lang="de"] .en,
html[lang="de"] .sl {
    display: none;
}

html[lang="sl"] .de,
html[lang="sl"] .en {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was error in my usage of setLang. Missing ' '...

wrong:

```
<body onload="setLang(<?echo substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);?>);">
```

right:

```
<body onload="setLang('<?echo substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);?>');">
```

Tnx, Rick Hitchcock, your comment give me a hint.

Comment: This is something that was not referred to at all in the question. If this was the answer, then the question wasn’t what was actually asked.

Comment: Yes it's true. I was somehow convinced that there is no problem in this part of the code but in css display block.